# How can I display XML in a browser with preserved whitespace / preformatted text?

Tags: html, css, xml, browser, whitespace

I'm hoping to create a simple xml language for formatting reports I have to write, something along the lines of

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="./report.css"?>    
<report>
<title>A Tale of Two Cities</title>
<author>Charles Dickens</author>
<code>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{       
    int x = 5;
}
</code>
</report>
```

Where `report.css` looks like

```
title { 
    font-family: serif;
    background: white; 
    color: #003 
}

author { 
    font-size: large;
    margin: 1em 0 
}

code { 
    font-style: italic 
}
```

etc. Problem is, I really need to keep the whitespace in some of the tags, like `code`. In html the `<pre>` tag does this, but I can't find any analog for xml, and my browser throws out all the whitespace when it renders the xml file. `<code xml:space="preserve">` does not fix the problem (as I understand it, because this is not a text-only node). Is there any hope for getting a browser to display this correctly (after which I can just print it to pdf)? Or otherwise generating a nice-looking report? Or should I just switch to LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS counterpart of the HTML `pre` tag is basically `white-space: pre` together with setting a monospace font. When styling XML, you also need to set the `display` property as needed, of course, to prevent elements from being inline by default.

```
code { 
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: Consolas, Courier, monospace;
}
```